# focused border not taking the whole container flutter

Tags: flutter

Here as shown the focused border is not taking the whole space. Can anybody explain why and fix it.

[image]

Here is the code of the TextField :

```
child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: _emailController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Enter your email',
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide:
                              const BorderSide(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                        ),
                        fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                        filled: true,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

I have tried adding the counterstyle but it is of no use !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the image shared of the code... you Padding left is pushing the bordered textfield to the left which is causing the space of 20 to the left...

Remove the Padding widget it should allow the textfield to have the complete border and to give padding inside the Text field use

```
TextField(
  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Enter Something',
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
  ),
)
```

This would give padding around the text inside the textfield ...

If you want to give padding to only the left side as you have now in your TextField you can use the below code...

```
TextField(
      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Enter Something',
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left:20.0),
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reason of Error:**
Padding
You provided left padding to TextFormField due to which only its left side gets padding and other sides are occupied whole container.
**Solution:**
Remove padding from TextFormField

Answer (score 0):

you can either remove the Padding widget or set the left padding of the TextField to 0,

```
child: TextField(
  controller: _emailController,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Enter your email',
    border: InputBorder.none,
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
    ),
    fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
    filled: true,
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0), // or remove this line
  ),
),
```